# Gray background mysteriously appears when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is selected (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, tableview

When I click my cell (in my table view), the entire background turns gray.  I have added the following code in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
stationFeedCell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

and no success. It still adds this obnoxious gray background.  I cannot figure out why this is occurring.  There is no elements in the view, just a white background that turns gray when it is selected.  I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone experiencing this issue, if the code doesnt work when placed in cellForRowAtIndexPath, place it in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.  When I did that it worked.

All the other sources online tell you to put it specifically in cellForRowAtIndexPath.. This is not always the case.

Comment: No, do not put `stationFeedCell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method. That's not the correct solution. If you don't want a row to be selected, return `nil` from the `willSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method.

Comment: I tried that.  But my solution was the only way that worked.  I know its unconventional but it works.